# Injectivity radius and covering radius

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have some basic confusion around the relationship between injectivity radius and evenly covered neighborhoods.

Suppose a Riemannian manifold $M$ has positive injectivity radius $c_1>0$. Let $\widetilde{M}$ be a covering space of $M$. Then does it follow that there exists a constant $c_2>0$ such that each point $x\in M$ has a neighborhood of radius $c_2$ that is evenly covered by $\widetilde{M}$?

Comment: The natural Riemannian metric on $\widetilde M$ is the pullback metric. Thus the answer is yes.

Comment: Is it obvious that the injectivity radius of the pullback metric at $x\in\widetilde{M}$ is at least as large as the injectivity radius at $p(x)\in M$, where $p$ is the projection map?

Comment: @ougoah: Yes, because each normal ball is simply-connected.